# Do we need to update the PWA app on Play Store to release new changes?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Do we need to update the PWA app on Android Play Store or Apple's App Store to release new changes or it automatically cleans-up the cache and show the new changes over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this blogpost [Google Play Store now open for Progressive Web Apps by Firtman](https://medium.com/@firt/google-play-store-now-open-for-progressive-web-apps-ec6f3c6ff3cc), if you need to update your app in Google Play Console:

> You don’t need to upload your app again if you change web
>   content — unless you change the app completely as per the store rules.
>   You will continue updating your app through Service Workers and new
>   deploys to your server. You will have to create and upload another APK
>   only if you want to change metadata, native code, or icons.